# Matrix operations on SAS

Tags: sas

I have a single line/multi column matrix, multiplied by a square matrix. SAS gives me a single line result.  So far, from what I remember from college math, and asking people, okay.

But the line from SAS that does it is this one:

fieldA = matrix1`*matrix2[,1:fieldB]

while I understand "fieldA = matrix1`*matrix2", I have no idea what [,1:fieldB] does, and I can't seem to find any document that explains it.

Comment: Curious, you asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367141/sas-trouble-with-field-functions/14367633#14367633 not that long ago - basically the same question just slightly differently phrased, no?

Comment: they did came from the same problem. The "(edit)" part on that other question was posted before this one - I asked here since it was a different problem and did get any attention at all there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix2[,1:fieldB]` is subsetting matrix2.  It includes all rows of matrix2, and only those columns that are included in the list 1:fieldB.  Presumably fieldB identifies the number of columns in matrix1 (which become rows when transposed) so the * works [`matrix1'` rows must equal matrix2 columns for the operation to be legal].

For example, imagine matrix1 is the following matrix:

```
[1,3,5]
```

and matrix2 is the following matrix:

```
[1,2,3,4,
 4,5,6,7,
 8,9,10,11,
 13,14,15,16]
```

Now,

```
matrix1`*matrix2
```

is illegal - matrix1` has 3 rows (transposed) and matrix2 has 4 columns.  So:

```
matrix1`*matrix2[,1:3]
```

will now be legal, yielding the matrix product of matrix1` by the first 3 columns of matrix2.